# How to create sublists of a list based on the relation between their elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large data set looking like this:

```
list1 = {{1, 1, a1}, {1, 1, a2}, {1, 1, a3}, {1, 2, b1}, {1, 2, 
 b2}, {1, 2, b3}, {1, 2, b4}, {1, 2, b5}, {10, 3, c1}, {10, 3, 
 c2}, {10, 3, c3}, {10, 3, c4}, {10, 3, c5}}
```

I need to choose the elements based on the same first and second elements and put them in new list. New lists should look like :

```
list2 = {{1, 1, a1}, {1, 1, a2}, {1, 1, a3}}
list3 = {{1, 2, b1}, {1, 2, b2}, {1, 2, b3}, {1, 2, b4}, {1, 2, b5}}
list4 = {{10, 3, c1}, {10, 3, c2}, {10, 3, c3}, {10, 3, c4}, {10, 3, 
 c5}}
```

Could you please help me in doing that?

Answer (score 6):

```
list1 = {{1, 1, a1}, {1, 1, a2}, {1, 1, a3}, {1, 2, b1}, {1, 2, 
    b2}, {1, 2, b3}, {1, 2, b4}, {1, 2, b5}, {10, 3, c1}, {10, 3, 
    c2}, {10, 3, c3}, {10, 3, c4}, {10, 3, c5}};
```

---

Using `SplitBy`:

```
{list2, list3, list4} = SplitBy[list1, Most@# &]

% // Column
```

[image]

Comment: I may have 100 lists, list1 ,list2, list3, ..., list1000 . This can help but since I do not know how many sublists are exactly there in the main list writing the left part is challenging

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi You don't have to set `{list2, list3...}`, you can just put everything in one variable, `newlists` for example - it will be a list of lists.

Comment: @MelaGo Thanks to mention it! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
list =
  {{1, 1, a1}, {1, 1, a2}, {1, 1, a3}, {1, 2, b1}, {1, 2, b2}, 
   {1, 2, b3}, {1, 2, b4}, {1, 2, b5}, {10, 3, c1}, {10, 3, c2}, 
   {10, 3, c3}, {10, 3, c4}, {10, 3, c5}};
```

Using `GatherBy`

```
{a, b, c} = GatherBy[list, Most]
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
{a, b, c} = SequenceCases[list1, {{x_, y_, _}, {x_, y_, _} ...}]
```

Both return

```
{{{1, 1, a1}, {1, 1, a2}, {1, 1, a3}},
 {{1, 2, b1}, {1, 2, b2}, {1, 2,b3}, {1, 2, b4}, {1, 2, b5}}, 
 {{10, 3, c1}, {10, 3, c2}, {10, 3, c3}, {10, 3, c4}, {10, 3, c5}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you potentially have 100's of sublists, let me make this suggestion.  Instead of using variable names like `list1`, `list2` ..., use `list[1]`, `list[2]`, ... .  This should make your work go much faster.

I would call the big container `data`, since `list[1]` is one of the sublists. We start by creating a list of unique keys from the data.

```
data = {
     {1, 1, a1}, {1, 1, a2}, {1, 1, a3}, 
     {1, 2, b1}, {1, 2, b2}, {1, 2, b3},
         {1, 2, b4}, {1, 2, b5}, 
     {10, 3, c1}, {10, 3, c2}, {10, 3, 3}, 
         {10, 3, c4}, {10, 3, c5}};

keys = DeleteDuplicates[Most /@ data];

(*  {{1,1}, {1,2}, {10,3}}   *)
```

Now there are several ways we can go, but the one I recommend is

```
Clear[list]
list[ndx_] := list[ndx] = Cases[data, Flatten[{keys[[ndx]], _}]]

list[3]

(*  {{10,3,c1},{10,3,c2},{10,3,c3},{10,3,c4},{10,3,c5}}   *)
```

The advantage of this method is that no list is actually generated until it is used in an expression.  Each list is saved when it is generated, so it is generated only once. This makes the method scalable, so it can be used with any number of keys/sublists.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation

Answer (score 3):

Using [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
{list2, list3, list4} = Values[GroupBy[list1, #[[{1, 2}]] &]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by iterating through the elements in your original list and grouping them based on the same first and second elements. Here's how you can do it in Python:

```
list1 = [[1, 1, 'a1'], [1, 1, 'a2'], [1, 1, 'a3'], [1, 2, 'b1'], [1, 2, 'b2'], [1, 2, 'b3'], [1, 2, 'b4'], [1, 2, 'b5'], [10, 3, 'c1'], [10, 3, 'c2'], [10, 3, 'c3'], [10, 3, 'c4'], [10, 3, 'c5']]

# Create a dictionary to store the grouped lists
grouped_lists = {}

for item in list1:
    key = tuple(item[:2])  # Use the first two elements as the key
    if key not in grouped_lists:
        grouped_lists[key] = []
    grouped_lists[key].append(item)

# Convert the dictionary values to lists
result_lists = list(grouped_lists.values())

# Print the result
for i, sublist in enumerate(result_lists, start=2):
    print(f"list{i} = {sublist}")
```

This code will create a dictionary grouped_lists where the keys are tuples of the first and second elements from your original list, and the values are lists of items that have the same key. Finally, it converts the dictionary values to lists and prints the result lists as list2, list3, list4, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! This is not the forum for Python as such this answer will likely be closed.